# Comparison values in FOR loop are not associating to correct vector elements when loop completes. - Code Review

Tags: for-loop, initialization

I am having two issues I believe. They have to do with i) initializing the vectors and ii) getting the `smallest` and `greatest` values to correspond to the correct values in the vector.

I've tried a couple of things:

When I initialize `smallest` and `greatest` I always run into the problem that both values begin with `0` as their initial value. I attempted to manually enter a value to initialize both variables (`smallest = distance[i]`, but that didn't really work because my vectors are empty initially.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main()
{
// Read a sequence of double values into a vector

vector <double> distance = {};                  // declaring the vector named "distance"
double sum = 0;
double smallest;
double greatest;

for (double x = 0; cin >> x;) {     // read into distance, to terminate putting values in vector use anything that is not of variable type of vector
    distance.push_back(x);                  // put distance into vector
    cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i = i + 1) {   // keeping track of elements in vector by displaying them
        cout << distance[i] << '\n';
    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i = i + 1) {                   // adding up all values of vector by iterating through all elements
    sum = sum + distance[i];                
    }

cout << "The total sum of all the elements in the vecotr is: " << sum << 
'\n';   



for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i = i + 1) {           // determining the smallest value in the vector
    if (smallest > distance[i]) {
        smallest = distance[i];
    }


}

cout << "The smallest value in the vector is: " << smallest << '\n';

for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i = i + 1) {     // determining the greatest value in the vector
    if (greatest < distance[i]) {
        greatest = distance[i];
    }
}

cout << "The greatest value in the vector is: " << greatest << '\n';

cout << "The mean distance between two neigbouring cities is: " << sum / distance.size() << '\n';
```

}

What suggestions/ hints could somebody provide me to work through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assign proper value after filling the vector.

```
vector <double> distance = {};      // declaring the vector named "distance"
double sum = 0;
double smallest;
double greatest;

for (double x = 0; cin >> x;) {     // read into distance, to terminate putting values in vector use anything that is not of variable type of vector
    distance.push_back(x);          // put distance into vector
    cout << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < distance.size(); i = i + 1) {   // keeping track of elements in vector by displaying them
        cout << distance[i] << '\n';
    }
}
if(!distance.empty()){ // if distance vector is not empty
    smallest = distance[0];
    greatest = distance[0];
}
```

Other common technique is to initialize `smallest` and `greatest` with values representing respectively +infinity and -infinity.
This way after first iteraton of loop the value of each variable will be in fact `distance[0]`.

```
#include <limits>

(...)

double smallest = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double greatest = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
```

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I'll probably use the first one in my program because I haven't reached far enough in the book to use the `numeric` standard library, even though  mathematically it makes more sense to me.....would this also help with the problem I'm having with my `for` loops?

Comment: The suggestion doesn't seem to be helping with writing the correct value sin the loops.